# Material Design Lite prevents jQuery UI components from sticking to its input fields while scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, timepicker, material-design-lite

jQuery UI autocomplete and datepicker components normally stick to their parent input element even when some scrolling action happens.
Using the Material Design Lite framework seems to prevent them from moving around with their associated input field. Instead they keep the initial position

Overwriting the given MDL code and changing the `position: absolute` of the `.mdl-layout__container` to `position: relative` seems to fix the jQuery UI problem but unfortunately breaks the Material Design Lite structure.

```
.mdl-layout__container {
position: absolute; // --> change to "relative"
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

I created a Pen which replicates this problem and uses JQuery UI autocomplete and datepicker as well as the jQuery Plug-in "[Timepicker](http://timepicker.co/)"
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/bkroggel/full/EygrXB/)

Comment: Those elements of Jquery UI are positioned relative to the body and seems like the material-design lite "fakes" the scroll of the document on an inner element `mdl-layout__content`; then the `body`never scroll and the elements remain on the position.